# JSF EL binding parameters work on Glassfish 3 but not on JBoss 6

Tags: java, jsf-2, jboss6.x

Below is the exception:

> 10:23:50,325 SEVERE
>   [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context]
>   (http-/127.0.0.1:18080-1) javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException:
>   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /auth/common/textSyncLockRow.xhtml
>   @29,45 value="#{customerMaintenanceView.getSyncLockInfo(tableName,
>   fieldName).synced}": The class
>   'com.jeldwen.cdm.view.CustomerMaintenanceView$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy'
>   does not have the property 'getSyncLockInfo'.
>
> > at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:857)
> >     at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:739)
> >     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
> >     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
> >     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
> >     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
> >     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
> >     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
> >     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
> >     at org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel.processUpdates(Panel.java:288)
> >     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
> >     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
> >     at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.processUpdatesOfFacetsAndChilds(ComponentUtils.java:444)
> >     at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabView.processUpdates(TabView.java:377)
> >     at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:281)
> >     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
> >     at  javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
> >     at org.primefaces.component.layout.Layout.processUpdates(Layout.java:240)
> >     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
> >     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
> >     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1223)
> >     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
> >     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
> >     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
> >     at org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.listener.request.DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.execute(DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.java:75)
> >     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
> >     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
> >     at  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
> >     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
> >     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
> >     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:499)
> >     at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
> >     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
> >     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
> >     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
> >     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
> >     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
> >     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
> >     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
> >     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Caused by:
>   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /auth/common/textSyncLockRow.xhtml
>   @29,45 value="#{customerMaintenanceView.getSyncLockInfo(tableName,
>   fieldName).synced}": The class
>   'com.jeldwen.cdm.view.CustomerMaintenanceView$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy'
>   does not have the property 'getSyncLockInfo'.
>
> > at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:133)
> >     at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:822)

Code from xhtml:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox 
    disabled="#{!customerMaintenanceView.isLockEnabled('corpcust', 'name')}" 
    value="#{customerMaintenanceView.getSyncLockInfo('corpcust', 'name').locked}" 
    onchange="flagDirty()">
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Code from ViewScoped bean:

```
public CdmSyncInfo getSyncLockInfo(String tableName, String fieldName) {
    return controller.getSyncInfo(tableName, fieldName);
}
```

Code from SessionScoped controller:

```
public CdmSyncInfo getSyncInfo(String tableName, String fieldName) {
CdmSyncInfo value = new CdmSyncInfo();
    for (CdmSyncInfo info : tdrWorking.getCustomerSyncInfos()) {
        if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(tableName, info.getTableName()) && StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName, info.getFieldName())) {
            value = info;
            break;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Question:  This works great running on Glassfish 3, what do I need to do to clear up the exception that is occurring on JBoss EAP 6.2?

Comment: Check to make sure that the version of EL supplied with the JSF version distributed with your JBoss, is El 2.2 (although it appears that the EL parser didn't have a problem with the `disabled` expression).

Comment: Thanks kolossus 20, I did confirm that it is EL 2.2.

Comment: Fixed by creating a model with 160 plus sync and lock fields.
So this line: 
value="#{customerMaintenanceView.getSyncLockInfo('corpcust', 'name').locked}"
became:
value="#{customerMaintenanceView.corporateSyncLock.legalNameLocked}"